# How to shift the entire numpy array, with wrapping

Tags: python, numpy

Not sure how to best title this question, but basically I would like to generate a new numpy array to be based on an existing array.  The only difference is that the values have been shifted to an index I specify.  Also assume that wrapping is required.

For simplicity, consider the base array:

```
[[0,1,2],
 [3,4,5],
 [6,7,8]]
```

If I want the zero (0) or the first element from the base array to be shifted at (0,1), it will be:

```
[[2,0,1],
 [5,3,4],
 [8,6,7]]
```

If I want the first element moved at (2,2) it will be:

```
[[4,5,3],
 [7,8,6],
 [1,2,0]]
```

Comment: I assume the 5 in matrix_2 position [2, 0] should be an 8. Can't edit because the edit is "too short" per SO requirements.

Comment: Yes, sorry typo.  I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Depending on how often you do this, you might want to consider a [ring buffer](https://github.com/eric-wieser/numpy_ringbuffer) instead. The answer recommending `np.roll` is O(n).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [numpy.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html). 
For instance, for the first output you can roll 1 index to the right, meaning along axis 1:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]])
x_shifted = np.roll(x, shift=1, axis=1)
```

Due to commutativity you can roll twice (once along each dimension) for the two-directional cyclic permutation effect:

```
x_double_shifted = np.roll(np.roll(x, shift=2, axis=1), shift=2, axis=0)
```

Obviously can be done more "pretty" ;-)
Good luck!